# Лучше использовать семантические элементы html типо <cite>, <b>, <u> или всё что можно описывать в css?

Tags: html, css, чистый-код

Где-то написано что семантика важна, а где-то написано что всё что можно сделать в CSS нужно делать в CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html теги используются для создания разметки и структуры документа. CSS по определению используются для стилизации HTML элементов. Советую использовать CSS для стилизации каких-либо элементов, а семантику HTML - для реализации скелета (позиционировании блоков). 
Правда, нигде не запрещено использовать семантику, но отталкиваясь от предназначения инструментов можно сделать вывод о использовании CSS или HTML.